# How can we test an API's rate limit using gatling tool?

Tags: api, gatling, scala-gatling, rate-limiting

I am new to exploring gatling and I'm trying to achieve a different case in testing rate limits. Firstly, is gatling a good tool to test rate limits? Also, what in-built functions/methods can I use to call a single http API call certain no. of times within a time window for a single virtual user ; to hit the rate limit?

Answer (score 1):

Gatling can be used for that sort of thing, yes.

Gatling lets you define scenarios that have looping constructs and also allows specifying the number of users executing your scenarios concurrently, so you have a large degree of flexibility.

Check out the tutorials on the Gatling site for examples